# Mapping MySQL column names to variable names

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I use **PDO** and use `FETCH_INTO` like

```
...
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
$query->execute();
```

I have a little problem. PHP variables are **camelCase**, but MySQL column names are **with underscores**. So I have `creationDate` vs `creation_date`.

Should I rename one side of equation to match the other one or do some 1:1 "mapping" via `__set` magic method (with **switch** command)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at symfony's sfInflector class it does the same job (in camelize method):

http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/util/sfInflector.class.php

Here's the extracted code:

```
$tmp = $lower_case_and_underscored_word;
$tmp = sfToolkit::pregtr($tmp, array('#/(.?)#e'    => "'::'.strtoupper('\\1')",
                                     '/(^|_|-)+(.)/e' => "strtoupper('\\2')"));
```

And the code from sfToolkit:

```
public static function pregtr($search, $replacePairs)
{
  return preg_replace(array_keys($replacePairs), array_values($replacePairs), $search);
}
```